# What/why `loop` passes as a block parameter to the block

Tags: ruby, loops, infinite-loop

[`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) creates an infinite loop, basically creating an iterator that returns dummy `Qnil` value:

```
loop.with_index do |what, index|
  puts [what, index].inspect # what == Qnil, returned from iterator
  break
end
#⇒ [nil, 0]
```

We likely can not have an iterator yielding void, that’s why. Now the question is (thanks @Stefan for making a wording clear): **why `loop.peek_values` returns an empty array, not `[nil]`**?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Why should `loop` yield an index?

Comment: @Stefan because it makes it handy and because it can not yield nothing, what makes chained calls look ugly due to mandatory but redundant underscore.

Comment: You could use `0.step do |index|` instead ...

Comment: Yes, I could, but it reads [IMHO] way less self-expressive. I got your reasoning and upvotes on your first comment; if there won’t be any helpful answer within one hour, I will remove the question. The main reason I have it asked is that is likely the first case when ruby acts contr-intuitive to me.

Comment: Actually, `loop` does `yield` nothing: `loop.peek_values` returns `[]`, not `[nil]`.

Comment: @Stefan. Now I am totally lost. If it were yielding nothing, `loop.with_index` should’ve yielded `index`, not `nil, index`.

Comment: `with_index` is inconsistent in this regard (I'd say _broken_). When using `with_index`, you cannot distinguish between `yield` and `yield nil` or between `yield :foo, :bar` and `yield [:foo, :bar]` any more.

Comment: @Stefan ok, it seems I got it. BTW, `each_with_object` behaves the same way as `with_index`. These `with_*` internally have a strict signature with not splatted two parameters (first for an item, second for whatever.) An item might be “multiassigned” using parentheses inside bars in block parameters declaration. But since there are _two_ mandatory parameters, this `nil` is unavoidable. Thanks!

Comment: The reason why `loop` doesn't `yield` an index is simple and has also been discussed on the Ruby Issue Tracker (where adding an index was proposed): it's intended for infinite loops, in which case the index (which isn't even used 99% of the time) takes infinite time to increment and infinite memory to store. Now, I don't know about you, but my PC doesn't have infinite RAM. Even when not used for infinite loops, it means that storing the index needs O(n) space. And since `Integer`s are immutable, incrementing the index needs to copy the index which takes O(log n) time.

Comment: People tend to react strangely to a loop that gets bigger and slower with each iteration

Comment: @JörgWMittag “storing the index needs `O(n)` space”—I do not see any reasonable explanation of why should we store the whole index. Also, `0.step { }` does not gorge all the memory, nor increases the memory consumed constantly.

Comment: @mudasobwa: How are you going to increment the index if you don't know what it is? You need to store what the index was at the last iteration so you can increment it for the next iteration. O(n) space is wrong, obviously, that was a typo, it's O(log n), fortunately I got that right in the next sentence. How long did you run the test? The memory increase is rather slow, O(log n). You need about 9 quintillion iterations until you overflow `Fixnum` into `Bignum`, at which point you should see a memory increase from 4 Bytes to 8 Bytes plus overhead for the object header.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, this is what I see. There is no chance this +DWORD jumps, actually giving `O(log log n)`, will eat the memory even on my Nokia 3310, though. Anyway, I got the explanation, thank you and @Stefan.